# Difference in Emission Node

Tags: texturing

I am not sure if there is an answer to this, but what is the difference between plugging in a texture to the Emission in Principled BSDF and using a Mix Shader to apply it to an Emission shader? Is there anything different in the way things appear?
[image]

Option 1 shows the texture being applied to the Emission slot.

Option 2 shows the texture being applied to the Emission shader instead of the Principled.

Comment: The equivalent would be an Add Shader, not a Mix Shader. One difference is the order of alpha and emission; Principled does emission first. See what happens if you set Alpha=0.

Comment: I see now. Thank you for helping me understand.